# Remove old temporary files when user is logged out

Tags: python, session, flask, temporary-files

I have a view that takes logged in user input then runs a function to produce a report. The result is returned in an HTML page. I render the report to PDF as well.

I create a PDF with the content from my function and save it in some folder on the server. I don't want to have my server filled with files from every run, so I create a temporary folder (in tmpfs) for each user when they log in and save the path in their session, which is not permanent.

```
session['temp_path'] = '/dev/shm/<random_uuid>/'
```

The user may log out by clicking a log out button, or their session might expire.  How can I remove the user's temporary folder after they are logged out?

Comment: What's random_uuid? Is uuid the  user ID?

Comment: @felipsmartins random_uuid is just a label for their folder, it's just random name for their folder. UUID is chosen only to have an unique name for the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested in this question I solved it another way. I do not check if the user logs out or create any cron script respectively.

I created an Object that runs a counting thread for every pdf created. After elapsed time, pdf is deleted.

Code looks like this:

```
class TimeSet(set):
    def add(self, item, timeout):
        set.add(self, item)
        t = threading.Thread(target=timeout_set_remove, args=(self, item, timeout))
        t.start()

def timeout_set_remove(my_set, item, timeout):
    time.sleep(timeout)
    os.remove(str(item))
    my_set.remove(item)
```

In my flask app I use it like this:

```
set = TimeSet()
set.add(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(src_path, pdf_name)), app.config['PDF_PERSISTENCE'])
```

where **pdf_name** is the name of created pdf, **src_path** is the path to the file. The persistence time is defined in my config file.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the log out button does the same thing as expiring the session, right?

There are two ways you can do this: 1) add code to the session expiration routine that cleans up the temporary files, and/or 2) write a `cron` script that checks for active sessions and cleans up the temporary files for inactive sessions.

Comment: Click does the same thing. But I don't know about any function that represents your "expiration routine"... I could put the command in logout function, but I'm not sure if the same function is called when the user is automatically kicked out...

Comment: About the 'cron' script, how RAM or power consuming could this task be for a server? What is the best way how to design this cron script? I can imagine to create eg. APScheduler with a job to remove a folder, but how to tell it when to do its job? How to check if session for user logged in before eg. an hour still exists?

Comment: I think you need to research Flask sessions to understand how a session expires and if it's the same as when they log out in your code.  Yes, you can use APScheduler instead of cron, but you should ask that as another question.